# Mean squares aproximation constant finding

Tags: analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods

Measurments $(t_k, C_k), t=1..n ; t_k, C_k > 0$ suggest that $C(t) = \frac{1}{At + Bsin(t) + 2}$. Using mean square approximation find probable values for constants $A$ and $B$. Should I start from $\frac{\partial}{\partial A} = 0 $ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial B} = 0 $? Also could you help me with calculating these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the model $$C(t) = \frac{1}{At + B\sin(t) + 2}$$ is nonlinear with respect to its parameters and, so, nonlinear regression is required which means that "good" estimates must be provided in order to start the calculation.

To get these estimates, you could start using a multilinear regression (with no intercept) for the model $$y(t)=At + B\sin(t) $$ based on data points $(t_k, y_k)$ where $y_k=\frac 1 {C_k}-2$. So, you get more than likely good estimates $A_0,B_0$ to start with.

You could even do it simpler using the model $$z(t)=A+ B v(t)\quad ,\quad z_k=\frac{\frac 1 {C_k}-2} {t_k}\quad ,\quad v_k=\frac{\sin(t_k)}{t_k}$$ and use the standard formulae for linear regression. This corresponds to a full linearization of the model.

But, if the data are in errors, the work is not finished since what is measured is $C$ and not $y$ or $z$.

If you have a nonlinear regression tool, the problem now becomes simple. Otherwise, you need to minimize the function $$SSQ=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(C_k- \frac{1}{At_k + B\sin(t_k) + 2} \right)^2$$ and, whatever could be the method you will use for this minimization, you will need $$\frac {dSSQ} {dA}  \qquad \frac {dSSQ} {dB} $$ and to solve for $A,B$ $$\frac {dSSQ} {dA} =0 \qquad \frac {dSSQ} {dB} =0$$ since you want $SSQ$ to be minimum. As you suspected, this will require the derivatives of the pieces.

$$\frac {dSSQ} {dA} =2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{ t_k }{(A t_k+B \sin
   (t_k)+2)^2}\left(C_k-\frac{1}{A t_k+B \sin (t_k)+2}\right)$$ 
$$\frac {dSSQ} {dB} =2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{ \sin(t_k) }{(A t_k+B \sin
   (t_k)+2)^2}\left(C_k-\frac{1}{A t_k+B \sin (t_k)+2}\right)$$ This makes two nonlinear equations for the two unknowns $A,B$ in which you see appearing the derivatives of the model with respect to its parameters.

But the problem becomes more complex because for solving these equations, if you use Newton-Raphson method, you will again need the derivatives of the expressions with respect to $A,B$.

For sure, you could make things slightly easier to write if you consider that the model is $$C(t) = \frac{1}{At + Bu + 2}$$ where $u=\sin(t)$.

**Edit**

To illustrate the above, let me consider the following data points $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 t & C \\
 0.5 & 0.46 \\
 1.0 & 0.43 \\
 1.5 & 0.41 \\
 2.0 & 0.40 \\
 2.5 & 0.40 \\
 3.0 & 0.41 \\
 3.5 & 0.42 \\
 4.0 & 0.43 \\
 4.5 & 0.43 \\
 5.0 & 0.41
\end{array}
\right)$$

Making the transformation I suggested gives
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 v & z \\
 0.958851 & 0.347826 \\
 0.841471 & 0.325581 \\
 0.664997 & 0.292683 \\
 0.454649 & 0.250000 \\
 0.239389 & 0.200000 \\
 0.047040 & 0.146341 \\
 -0.100224 & 0.108844 \\
 -0.189201 & 0.081395 \\
 -0.217229 & 0.072351 \\
 -0.191785 & 0.087805
\end{array}
\right)$$

Performing the linear regression gives $$z=0.132303+0.235168 v$$ so we have our estimates. Using these parameters, recomputing the $C$'s shows $SSQ=1.134\times 10^{-4}$.

Now, let us go to the complete nonlinear regression starting with these value; we obtain $$C=\frac{1}{0.131816 t+0.250430 \sin (t)+2}$$ to which corresponds $SSQ=6.879\times 10^{-5}$ that is to say almost twice smaller than what was obtained from the linearized model.

Not too bad, isn't it ?